Main Log4Net is working but nested loggers are not
I am working on a legacy .Net Framework 4.5.2 console app that uses Log4Net for logging issues that has been around at least 7+ years. One thing I am noticing is that logging in the main project is working as expected but logging is not working for the other projects in the solution that it calls.
When I am debugging, I see 2 appenders in the main project when logging as expected but when I look at the other projects that are nested in the main app, there are 0 appenders on the logger. The nested projects use a syntax like below to initialize the logger and pass it in to SetLog().
SetLog(log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType));

I can get the logging working correctly if I hard-code the string name to the main logger like below (where "Digest" is the name of the main logger). Unfortunately, the nested project is called from other projects besides the ones that use the "Digest" logger so I cannot hard-code it like this.
SetLog(log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("Digest"));

My understanding is that the nested project needs to have a reference in AssemblyInfo.cs like below and that sets up hierarchical logging, but does not seem to work.
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator( Watch = true )]

Any ideas what I might be missing? I can post additional configuration if necessary.

Are you mixing .Net Framework and .NetStandard code? There are a bug in log4net NetStandard logging repository. I use this code
var repo = LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() ?? Assembly.GetCallingAssembly() ?? Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()); XmlConfigurator.Configure(repo, xmlElement); 

No, definitely .Net Framework, but thanks for the info.
